# How to know each result of the query is accessed when reading data from Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android project whose database is on Firebase. At some point, I need to get the names of all people whose age is equal to some given age. So here's my code:

```
    peopleRef.orderByChild("age").equalTo(age).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            nameArray.add(name);
            //showNames();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

After putting the names in the array, I need to use this array in another function called showNames(). But because of the asynchronous nature of Firebase database, I can't reach the array outside the onChildAdded. The problem is, I need to call showNames() only once, when all the names are added to the array. How can I know when the query visited all people and finished adding names to the array, so I can call showNames()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ValueEventListener` instead and iterate through the children, adding them to the array:

```
peopleRef.orderByChild("age").equalTo(age).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                nameArray.add(name);
            }
            showNames();
        }
});
```

Comment: You're on a roll again Rosário! Thanks for helping Firebase developers!

Comment: It's always a pleasure :) @FrankvanPuffelen